# Excel lookup 2 Values

Tags: excel

I'm sorry if this is an obvious question, but I've been searching and can't seem to figure this out..

```
Cost TableCost Table
Employee    Date      Hours
2           03/16/16    8
2           03/17/16    8
2           03/20/16    8
3           03/21/16    8
3           03/22/16    8
5           03/23/16    10
6           03/24/16    4
6           03/28/16    5

Time Clock Table
Employee    Date      Hours
2           03/16/16    1
2           03/17/16    3
2           03/20/16    2
3           03/21/16    5
3           03/22/16    4
5           03/23/16    7
6           03/24/16    7
6           03/28/16    7
```

I just want to lookup on this table to see how many hours each employee  worked on a certain date.  They are cheating the system and we need to find out who's short.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If Employee is column A and you want to look up the date, why do you use C2 in the lookup? Also you need to provide the structure of the other table for anyone to come up with a formula.

Comment: Sorry. I made it more clear.  I hope!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a formula like this

```
=INDEX(TableCostTable[Hours],MATCH([@Employee]&[@Date],INDEX(TableCostTable[Employee]&TableCostTable[Date],0),0))
```

It concatenates the name and the date and uses Index/Match to look up the same combination and returns the hours.  The formula uses structured references with the column names and header names. It will also work if you use sheet names and cell references, but don't use it with whole columns, because that will be very slow.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I have it set up exactly like yours and it didn't work.. So I tried this =INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A:A&B:B,INDEX([E:E]&[F:F],0),0)) and it's saying the syntax is not correct.   Any suggestions? I know you said don't do columns but I'm not sure what to do.  Thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need a `SUMIFS` rather than a `VLOOKUP`, in this case

```
=sumifs(Paytable!C:C, Paytable!A:A,2,Paytable!B:B,date(2016,3,17))
```

Comment: How would I add the date? It works but I have to change the date manually and there are a lot of rows.  Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: You can replace any part in there, by other references. With the information you've provided, that's pretty much all I can do.

Comment: It also seems to only look up the first employee number

Comment: @CNL, how can you expect a good answer if you don't provide the information we ask you to provide?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am trying my best.  I updated the initial question to be more clear.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this through a `SUMIFS` formula, such as:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, 2, B:B, "03/07/16")
```

What this is doing is summing all values in column `C` where column `A` is equal to 2 (for the employee) where column `B` is equal to 03/07/16.

Comment: You need to do something to make that last argument a date - currently it evaluates to the fraction *3/112*.

Comment: I can do that, but it doesn't work. I changed my original question to be more specific.  Thanks.